# Bash program exits when it runs no matter what

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to have the script exit if the user enters 'q'

here's the code:

```
echo "Enter Choice => "
    read target
if [[ $target=='q' ]]; then
  exit 1
else
  #do something
fi
```

However when I run it no matter what the input is, the script exits...

Comment: It's checking whether `"$target==q"` is a non-empty string. It's always non-empty, because no matter what `$target` is, `==q` is non-empty itself.

Comment: You need spaces -- `[[ $target = q ]]` -- if you want to compare against `q`. (`=` is preferred because it's valid in POSIX `test`, whereas `==` is a nonportable extension).

Comment: BTW, if you pasted your code into http://shellcheck.net/, it would link you to [SC2077](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2077), a page describing this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter Choice => "
    read target
if [[ $target == 'q' ]]; then
  exit 1
else
  #do something
  echo "do something..."
fi

~
```

Try this - spacing between the tokens $target, '==' and 'q' is important.

Comment: See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the Help Center, particularly the bullet point regarding questions which *...have already been asked and answered many times before*.

Comment: So its not the if loop thats bugging out but the comparison  operator?

Comment: the space between the comparison operator is important.